# Speech to Text Android App

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I'm trying to create a speech to text app, to get started I got sample code from android developer site. But when I try to run it on emulator it gives the error `"Application Speech recorder (process.com.speech.recognition) has stopped unexpectedly"`. How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you are getting below Force close:

[image]

Because **Android Emulator is not having any Audio Input to hook.** Instead attach the microphone or headphone and test it.